# Window doesn't update during $interval

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pass a function in  `$interval`, but not every parameter is updated in the console.

Plnkr link: https://plnkr.co/edit/rXAtMCXcZIV2HdlSiZVX?p=preview

```
vm.timer = $interval(function(){
  $scope.iterationCount++;
  vm.life.next;
}, $scope.time, $scope.iteration);
```

The above statement updates `$scope.iterationCount`, but doesn't update `vm.life.next`. The latter stays on the initial state.

When I do it like this:

```
vm.timer = $interval(vm.life.next, $scope.time, $scope.iteration);
```

`vm.life.next` updates, but then I have no way of updating `$scope.iterationCount`

Comment: I don't see any console in your code...

Comment: Sorry. By console I meant the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `vm.life.next` is the function updating life, then here

```
vm.timer = $interval(vm.life.next, $scope.time, $scope.iteration);
```

it gets called (inside an interval), but here

```
vm.timer = $interval(function(){
   $scope.iterationCount++;
   vm.life.next;
}, $scope.time, $scope.iteration);
```

it doesn't - `()` are missing. Should be `vm.life.next();`

Comment: Thank you so much!! I can't believe i wasted 3 hours on some missing parenthesis.